# In the OS X Contacts app (v7.1) how can I delete a group?

Tags: contacts, group

I've accidentally created a group in the Contacts app, below 'All Contacts'. How do I delete it?

If I remove the group name it renames itself to 'untitled group'. Here's a screenshot of what I see: [image: Contacts Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the group
- Click "Edit" in the menubar
- Click "Delete Group"
- Click Delete

Comment: Unbelievable... I'm so stupid (and it shows how much I expect context-sensitive menus on everything). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out all I needed to do on my MacBook Pro was highlight the contact, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the contact I was trying to get rid of was gone.